# iOS Delete Row from Tableview without deleting Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

I have a tableview embedded in a View Controller that is filled with core data results. The core data being displayed is editable by selecting a row and is related to other Core Data entities.

I want to delete a row from my tableview *without deleting the object*.

It seems fairly straight forward however there does not seem to be any obvious answers.

I have tried to use a second predicate `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"shouldDisplay = YES"];` which is a `BOOL` that when changing values of an object I wish to delete is set to `NO` in the `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method however this causes an error because `shouldDisplay` is not a valid keypath (which I have never had this issue in the past). I got this suggestion from this **[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20381884/deleting-a-row-in-tableview-without-deleting-core-data-entity)** which is the only relevant link I have found on stack.

Is there a simple way to delete a row from a table, be it simply excluding the data in the table or actually deleting a row, without permanently deleting the corresponding data?

**EDIT**

This is the most common suggestion I have read:

```
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

This does not work for me killing the app and gives this reason:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).

**UPDATE**

To see my code for how I am filling my tableview and what works/does not work, please see this **[PASTE BIN LINK](http://pastebin.com/hQBdc1SX)**. I am not populating using an array.

**Acknowledgment**

I was trying to use a BOOL in a predicate *without* having the BOOL "`shouldDisplay`" in my entity attributes. The predicate cannot work by searching the attribute for something declared in the class. It is a rookie error.

Comment: Make the fetched result array global and remove the object from the results array and reload the tableview

Comment: @Rose It seems like a long way around to put all the results into an array and then filter again. If it is the only option I will have to try it.

Comment: other way is you can delete the row of the uitableview

Comment: How without deleting the object? That's my question.

Comment: For the predicate try [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"shouldDisplay = %@", @(YES)];

Comment: @SkylerLauren thanks for the suggestion however it still doesn't work. It still states that it cannot find the keypath in the entity.

Comment: @SASmith on last thing I notice lately Xcode isn't actually updating the NSManagedObject subclass .h/.m that drove me nuts a couple of days ago. You might want to verify that it did because I imagine you added this after the fact. I had to delete instead of replace before it would work :/

Comment: @SkylerLauren It's updating as I have to go through a long process of verifying data before I get to this stage of deleting a row in a tableview. Issue is every option I have currently seen requires deleting the data as well for it to successfully delete a row. Really appreciate your time and effort to help.

Comment: @SASmith np that predicate thing should be an alright work around and hope you find why that isn't working. The only other option (although semi dangerous) is that I though the table  data would update when you delete and object in core data even if  you don't call save on the context. There may be a work around there where you use a different context and NEVER call save on it. Good luck and hope you find an answer.

Comment: your objects do have that keyPath? you added 'shouldDisplay' to the core data model?

Comment: Uh! I'm a Wally. Talk about a brain fart moment. No wonder the predicate won't work. Forget the Boolean check. It's not available because it's not in my entity which the predicate can only search.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to delete the cell use below.

```
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

If you want to remove object too, then add below statement.

```
[yourObjectArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

### Note:

After deleting the row if you reload table, then you will see that row again as you had not deleted that specific object from your array.

Comment: I have tried that but as stated in the question i am using and recovering core data and not an NSArray so it kills the app.

Comment: [yourObjectArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; won't delete the object from CD at all

Comment: @Daij-Djan : I KNOW... and OP want that... he don't want to delete object.. he just want to delete from  tableview...

Comment: quote: "if you want to remove object too, then add below statement."

Comment: @Daij-Djan : I read incorrectly... `[yourObjectArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` will remove object from array.. whats wrong?

Comment: nothing but that won't delete any object ... the OP doesn't even have an array ;) don't get why you show it :)

Answer (score 0):

I have fetching `core data` in `NSManagedObject` array and I had also getting same problem.

> The problem is.

I had deleting row from tableview before deleting from `NSManagedObject` array.

So just try it

First delete from your array I have used `NSManagedObject` so i have used

```
[mydata removeAtIndex:indexPath.row]
```

And then delete row from tableview using `deleteRowAtIndexPath` Method

> In `commitEditingStyle` Method

Comment: [myData removeAtIndex: indexPath.row]; is not a valid option.

Comment: It is the only valid option because when you delete the row from tableview using deleteRowAtIndexPath then first it will call two methods numberOfSectionsInTableView and numberOfRowsInSection and than after rest of statement will execute.

Comment: It's not a valid option because it is not an available option.

Comment: which type of array you used to store fetch result from core data??

Comment: I fetch results from an entity not an array.

Comment: If you want to delete a row from my tableview without deleting the object.than you have to first retrive an entity data into an array